# asp.net c# txt file to dropdownlist:

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need to populate a drop down list with a txt file.  I tried this but it isn't working.

```
protected void DropDownListCOUNTRY_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> country = new List<string>();
    country = File.ReadAllLines("../App_Data/txt/CountryList.txt").Select(x => x.Split('_')[0]).ToList();
    foreach (string countrysingle in country)
    {
        DropDownListCOUNTRY.Items.Add(new ListItem(countrysingle, countrysingle));
    }
}
```

This is the VB code that works in C#

```
if (this.IsPostBack == false) 
    {

        string path = MapPath("~/App_Data/txt/CountryList.txt");
        FileStream fp = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fp);
        string data;
        while ((data = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] v = data.Split(',');

            foreach (string entry in v)
            {
                DropDownListCOUNTRY.Items.Add(entry);
            }

        }
        reader.Close();
        fp.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What to you mean by "it isn't working"? Any exceptions being thrown? If so, could you please edit your question and paste the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: No errors and the drop down isn't getting populated by the text file.

Comment: Are you sure the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired? Because you fill the same ddl in it's on change method. The code itself is working fine (tested it)

Comment: So I actually just used the code that I wrote for this in vb and it works for C#...how is that happening?

Comment: I just tested those 6 lines without the SelectedIndexChanged event, but yeah it works in C#

Comment: I think it is good idea to provide sample of your text files & even better if you can provide isolated version of problem that you're trying to solve. What is DropDownListCountry & why are you comparing it with C# & VB.NET?

Comment: I agree with @Umang, please edit your question and paste the content of the text file (at least a few lines)

Comment: All it is is a list of all the country's in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The VB code in my initial question works.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to give variable declaration also in foreach loop like below

```
    foreach (string countrysingle in country) { 
DropDownListCOUNTRY.Items.Add(countrysingle); 
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I got this to work with vb but cannot get this in c# to save my life...../

Comment: Maybe try creating ListItem objects first and then adding them to the drop down list

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Like this DropDownListCOUNTRTY.Items.Add(New ListItem(countrysingle, countrysingle))

Comment: Oh yeah...like you would if it was a few items. this list is huge though.

Comment: Yeah . You can add it in the loop and check.if it also doesn't work, try debugging to see the list of strings coming in country once

Comment: It's not populating the list.  But no errors either.